# Drawbacks of changing certificate revocation mode

Tags: ssl-certificate

Recently our SSL certificate provider had an outage. Web services that used the certificate issued by the certificate provider had stopped working because we had web service RevocationMode set to "Online" (which is default for WCF services), meaning that "A revocation check is made using an online certificate revocation list (CRL)".

To make sure our services are available even when certificate provider goes down (at least by people who already accessed the web services before), we are thinking of switching to Revocation Mode - "Offline", meaning that "A revocation check is made using a cached certificate revocation list (CRL)". I've googled for extensively, but was not able to find out what are drawbacks of switching from "Online" revocation mode to an "Offline", cached mode.

What are the implications of moving our WCF Services to Offline checks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Online CRL checks are faster to revoke a certificate.
If you revoke your certificate due to a compromise an online check will reveal that immediately.

Offline CRL checks are comparatively slower.
If you revoke your certificate due to a compromise your clients will not find out until the next time they update their cached copy of the CRL.

So the implication is you are exposing your users to compromised certs for a longer period if you use offline (cached) mode validation.

---

A better solution from a security standpoint would be to make the online CRL redundant.
This requires some capital and maintenance investment, but allows you to continue taking advantage of the improved security available through online CRL checks.